# Request shopify cart.json stopped working with error 330

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

I use jQuery to get the cart data contents from Shopify and display it on another site. It just stopped working. Google Chrome shows the request is 'failed' and when I open this request in another tab Google shows:

```
Error 330 (net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED): Unknown error.
```

When I Google for this message I only get reports saying it has something todo with compression. Which is a bit difficult to debug as Shopify is a hosted webshop.

I use this method to get the cart contents:

```
Shopify.getCart = function(callback) {
  console.log("getCart")
  jQuery.ajax({url: 'http://shop-here/cart.json', dataType: 'jsonp', cache: false, success:
    function(cart){
      console.log("response: " + callback)
      console.log(cart)
      if (callback !== undefined && (typeof callback) === 'function') {
        callback(cart);
      }
      else {
        Shopify.onCartUpdate(cart);
      }
    }
  });
};
```

What is going wrong and how do I fix this?

Comment: I've reported an issue with Shopify regarding JSONP not working on several of their JSON endpoints. Still waiting to hear back.

Comment: I just got word that they fixed the issue. My stuff is back to normal. Give it a try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shopify fixed the issue. As the error messages indicated, it was an error on the Shopify servers.